# Sample size estimation for superiority/non-inferiority study

Tags: sample-size, statistical-power, clinical-trials, non-inferiority

I am trying to estimate sample size for a superiority/non-inferiority study between two diagnostic tests. I have the AUCs of Model0 (standard test) and Model1 (new test), and other required parameters. The TrialSize R package has functions [TwoSampleMean.NIS()](https://rdrr.io/cran/TrialSize/man/TwoSampleMean.NIS.html) and [TwoSampleProportion.NIS()](https://rdrr.io/cran/TrialSize/man/TwoSampleProportion.NIS.html).

Which of these is appropriate for my use case? Keeping in mind that I am comparing AUCs, which is neither a "group mean" nor a "rate" (correct?). Therefore should I use something else?

Comment: For superiority I think that easyROC might do the trick: http://www.biosoft.hacettepe.edu.tr/easyROC/ For non-inferiority, I am not sure yet.